# svchost.exe memory usage up to 4Gb every hour, how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, process, memory-usage

For some unknown reason, more or less every hour, one of the svchost.exe process (LocalServiceNoNetwork) of my Win 7 takes up to 4Gb of memory ! If I don't manually kill the process it makes the PC freeze for some minutes...

What's strange is that it never happened before, and I did nothing special.

When i have a look at the properties of this process, it says i've got *ntdll.dll!rtl user thread start* started 8 times. And when it stops everything's normal again.

What's going on and how can i fix this please ?
Any help much apreciated. thanks!

Comment: I'll take "Viruses or Malware" for $200, Alex.

Answer (score 1):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will tell you which services are running in a given `svchost.exe` process.  You can use that information to narrow down the range of services that you need to start/stop to see what is using all of your memory.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Process Explorer, in Task Manager in Windows 7 you can right click on any of the processes and click "Go To Service(s). This will highlight which services are being run by this process.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a sign of malware, [see my post here](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533)

Use the "Alternate Method"

Read the "EDIT" section also.

Answer (score 0):

svchost acts as a host for services running on your computer. Killing it will do you no good. The problem would likely be in a service that is running.

See all services by starting

```
services.msc
```

It shows you running services, and gives you the option of disabling them permanently.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer, but i didn't really find where to see the memory usage per service.

Anyway, I fixed this problem thanks to *Process Explorer* (free soft). 
This problem was due to the WWAN service (used to set up 3G connections). For an unknown reason this service doen't start on my computer. And trying to start every X minutes made my computer freeze. 
Well, so I desactivated this service.