# One particular instance of svchost.exe taking up awful lot of memory. Why?

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance, process, svchost

I have been observing that the process "**svchost.exe**" in my list of running processes keeps taking an awful lot of memory; close to 550MB at times!

There are multiple instances of svchost.exe running in my machine at anytime but one particular instance takes up hell lot of memory. I constantly need to keep killing this process to reclaim the memory.

Also, I have observed that whenever I kill this process, my windows goes into a Basic style theme and then after sometime, it comes back to normal suddenly (the glass type style and transparent windows and all).

This means that the process has restarted again and yet again it has started taking up too much memory.

Any suggestions on how this can be stopped? Despite having 8 gigs of RAM, my laptop keeps slowing down and I have to kill this process to make it work a little faster.

Comment: To find out more, see the answers under http://superuser.com/questions/303263/svchost-exe-memory-usage-up-to-4gb-every-hour-how-to-fix?rq=1. Then update your question with more info.

Comment: this is the WindowsUpdate service.

Comment: @magicandre1981 As you said, the windows update service is indeed responsible for taking up lots of memory. I stopped that and could observe significant reduction in the memory taken up by that process. However, I observed that after some time, the memory taken up by that process has increased again. I even ran an anti virus scan to see if there was malware, but there isn't. I wonder what else can be done to reduce the memory taken by that process. Thanks for your answer any way. :)

Comment: Run **tasklist /svc /fi "imagename eq svchost.exe"** and see which services are hosted by the svchost.exe. It can be superfetch.